# Why am I getting Segmentation fault in my code?

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

```
    Node* findMax(Node* root){
        Node* m=root;
        while(m!=NULL && m->right!=NULL){
            m=m->right;
        }
        return m;
    }
    // Returns the root of the modified BST after deleting the node with value X
    Node *deleteNode(Node *root,  int X)
    {
        Node *temp;
        if(!root)return NULL;
        else if(X<root->data)root->left=deleteNode(root->left,X);
        else if(X>root->data)root->right=deleteNode(root->right,X);
        else if(X==root->data){
            //data found
            if(root->left && root->right){//internal node to be deleted
                temp=findMax(root->left);//inorder predecessor
                root->data=temp->data;//replace by inorder predecessor
                root->left=deleteNode(root->left,root->data);//delete the duplicate left in left subtree
            }
            else{//node to be deleted is either leaf or has one child
                temp=root;
                if(root->left==NULL){  
                    root=root->right;
                }
                if(root->right==NULL){         
                    root=root->left;
                }
                free(temp);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

I can't find what is wrong in this code: Why is it throwing a segmentation fault?

Comment: Remember that `free(temp);` does not set `temp` or `root` to be `NULL` after freeing.

Comment: Did you try to debug first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part

```
                if(root->left==NULL){  
                    root=root->right;
                }
                if(root->right==NULL){         
                    root=root->left;
                }
```

When `root->left == NULL` is true, `root=root->right;` is executed.
Thanks to condition of previous `if` statement, `root->right` is `NULL` here and then
`root` is set to `NULL`.
Then, `root->right==NULL` is evaluated and `root` (`NULL`) is dereferenced.
This will cause Segmentation Fault.

To fix, the second condition will always be true when `root->left!=NULL`, so it should be replaced to `else` and have it execute only one of them.

```
                if(root->left==NULL){  
                    root=root->right;
                }
                else{         
                    root=root->left;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I almost missed that part.